# Does Twilio MessageResource.Price include carrier fees for SMS in the response

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When I get a price back when I call a Fetch to get a status of a message, it has Price and Segments.

I'm wondering if that includes Carrier fees as well? I don't know how common carrier fees are but say the normal pricing for 1 segments is 0.0075, could I see another message that is 1 segment and has 0.01 price?

I'm guessing I would see it on this return otherwise we could just use segments for pricing.

I'm using c# Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageResource

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-csharp/5.13.5/class_twilio_1_1_rest_1_1_api_1_1_v2010_1_1_account_1_1_message_resource.html#a7ef0b232aaacc27cd7764214f41549fc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Twilio support ticket I got:

"The carrier fees are already included in the price that you see in the messages you send, so for example, if you were to retrieve your messages using the Message Resource API, that carrier fee would be included in the price listed for each message. "

Comment: Is this no longer true?